# Docx-Python Change Text Opacity

Tags: python, docx

I'm replacing text in a docx file which originally has the text at 25 percent opacity, however when I execute the script, the opacity of the changed paragraphs returns back to 0 percent. Is there a way to program in the opacity similar to things like font size, italics, etc.? I didn't find anything in the docx-python documentation.

Edit: Here's the docx portion of the code.

```
styles = d.styles
style = styles.add_style('Main Text', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
mainStyle = d.styles['Main Text']
fontMain = mainStyle.font
fontMain.name = 'Montserrat Light'
fontMain.size = Pt(12)

styles = d.styles
style = styles.add_style('Main Run Text', WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER)
mainRunStyle = d.styles['Main Run Text']
fontRunMain = mainRunStyle.font
fontRunMain.name = 'Montserrat Light'
fontRunMain.size = Pt(12)

currentDate = datetime.date.today()
currentDateFormatted = currentDate.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
d.paragraphs[10].text = currentDateFormatted

d.paragraphs[12].text = 'Jimmy Newtron' #replace with argument
pName = d.paragraphs[12]
pName.style = d.styles['Main Text']

d.paragraphs[13].text = 'Lead Recruiter' #replace with argument
pTitle = d.paragraphs[13]
pTitle.style = d.styles['Main Text']

d.paragraphs[14].text = 'Mega Corp' #replace with argument
pCompany = d.paragraphs[14]
pCompany.style = d.styles['Main Text']

d.paragraphs[15].text = 'New York City, New York, United States' #replace with argument
pLocation = d.paragraphs[15]
pLocation.style = d.styles['Main Text']

d.paragraphs[17].runs[2].text = 'Jimmy Newtron' #replace with argument
rDear = d.paragraphs[17].runs[2]
rDear.style = d.styles['Main Run Text']

d.paragraphs[18].runs[2].text = 'Mega Corp' #replace with argument
rCompany = d.paragraphs[18].runs[2]
rCompany.style = d.styles['Main Run Text']

d.paragraphs[21].runs[3].text = 'Mega Corp' #replace with argument
rCompanyTwo = d.paragraphs[21].runs[3]
rCompanyTwo = d.styles['Main Run Text']

d.save('c:\\users\\sonorityscape\\desktop\\test.docx')
```

Comment: pls add the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found is to save the text as a run instead of a paragraph. For some reason it keeps the transparency/opacity you saved in the original document.